# Why is the Datatables Package Not Working Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, datatables

I have developed my project laravel 5.0 but, I want to install the package for **Data-tables**.  I have tried this package with below-mentioned versions.

```
 composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:^6.0

 composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:~5.0

 "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^6.6.0",

composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:~6.0
```

This package is not installing in my project. Please suggest me any other package for Datatables Laravel 5.

[image]

Comment: Does it return an error when you try to install it?

Comment: Yes,  It's returning the error.

Comment: Can you show us the error so we can try to help you? We can't guess what's going wrong.

Comment: wait, i was capturing screen shot for that error.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of composer?

Comment: this is my Composer version 1.2-dev (ec2660fe78ca40ff4415f5dd1a00a721b2e6df56) 2016-09-13 1
4:18:05

Comment: Can you reinstall composer so you have the latest version? It might fix your problem.

Comment: again same error is coming..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do is to add the following in your `composer.json` file:

```
"require": {
 "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~6.0"
}
```

after run `composer update` command in *cmd*

Hope this work for you!